# Pass more values in doInBackground AsyncTask Android

Tags: android

How to pass more values in the `doInBackground`

My `AsyncTask` looks like this.

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        {

        }
}
```

Is it possible somehow to pass more values on my `protected String DoInBackground`

for example: `protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl, String... otherUrl, Context context)`

And how to `execute` the `AsyncTask` after? `new DownloadFile.execute("","",this)` or something?

Comment: You can create argument-ed constructor DownloadFile class and then use those args anywhere in class body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String... sUrl
```

the three consecutive dots meaning more then one String. The **dots** are varargs

> And how to pass the Context?

you can force it adding a constructor that takes the Context as parameter:

```
private Context mContext;
public void setContext(Context context){
    if (context == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context can't be null");
    }
    mContext = context;
}
```

Comment: And how to pass the Context?

Answer (score 11):

you can send multiple parameters as you can send them as varargs. But you have to use same Type of parameter. So to do what you are trying you can follow any of the followings

**Option 1**

you can use a setter method to set some value of the class member then use those in doInBackGround. For example

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private Context context;
        public void setContext(Context c){
            context = c;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        {
              // use context here
        }
}
```

**Option 2**

Or you can use constructor to pass the values like

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private Context context;
        public DownloadFile (Context c){
            context = c;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        {
              // use context here
        }
}
```

Comment: With your suggestion I get `This field leaks a context object` warning.

Answer (score 5):

you can do something like this inside your doInBackground method:

```
String a = sUrl[0]
String b = sUrl[1]
```

execute AsyncTask in this way:

```
new DownloadFile().execute(string1,string2);
```

the first value : sUrl[0] will be the one passed from string1 and
surl[1] will be the second value passed i.e string2 !

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can pass more values in `constructor` but not in **`doInBackground`**

**Try this way**

```
 new DownloadFile(String sUrl,String other Url,Context context).execute();
```

***Async Task***

```
 private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    public DownloadFile(String url,String url2,Context ctx)
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    {

    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, for the following reasons :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl, String... otherUrl, Context context)
```

is not a valid method signature. The dots notations (Varargs) can only be used as the last parameter of the method. This restriction is because otherwise it would make polymorphism much more complex. In fact, how would java know which of your Strings go to `sUrl`, and which goes to `otherUrl`?

Moreover, `doInBackground` overrides a method from `AsyncTask`. As such, you cannot change the method signature.

What you can do, however, is  make those values members of your class and pass in the constructor of your `DownloadFile` class or add setters to set them before calling `execute`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use constructor

```
 private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            private Context context;
            public void DownloadFile(Context c,String one, int two){
                context = c;
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            {
                  // use context here
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new DownloadFile().execute(Str1,str2,str3,........);
```

this is one way to pass more url... if you want send more values in doinbackground method..

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<DataHolders, Integer, String> {
    public class DataHolders {
        public String url;
        public String myval;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(DataHolders... params) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

you can call the class with

```
DataHolders mhold = new DataHolders();
 new DownloadFile().execute(mhold,mhold2,mhold3,........);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ypu can create constructor to pass different type parameters and also strings data using String......str

```
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private Context context;
          byte[] byteArray;
        public DownloadTask (Context c,byte[] byteArray){
            context = c;
            byteArray=byteArray;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        {
              // use context here
     System.out.println(param[0]);
          }
  }



new DownloadTask(context,bytearray).excute("xyz");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new DownloadFile().execute("my url","other parameter or url");    
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            {
                try {
                    return downloadContent(sUrl[0], sUrl[1]); // call
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return "Unable to retrieve data. URL may be invalid.";
                }
            }
    }
```