# Android Calling TCP client method

Tags: java, android, tcpclient

I am calling a Service by pushing button a in UI. The service in return calls a TCP/IP Client method in a Class. Service starts without any problem but as soon as TCP/IP Client method is called it crashes the UI activity. I even tried to call this method directly without service and it still crashed. This class is not registered in the Manifest as an activity but I have declared following in the Manifest;

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

UI Activity;

```
 public class cfm extends AppCompatActivity {
 ............
 Acpt_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(cfm.this, Tx.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("EXTRA_M",msg + localip);
            extras.putString("EXTRA_IP",svrip);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            cfm.this.startService(intent);

           finish();
        }

    });

}
```

Service

```
    public class Tx extends Service {

    Atx atx = new Atx();


    @Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Toast.makeText(this, " TX Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = extras.getString("EXTRA_M");
    final String svrip = extras.getString("EXTRA_IP");

      try {
        atx.transmitAck(msg,svrip);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    stopSelf();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}



public Tx() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

The Class containing the TCP/IP Client method

```
   public class Atx {


public void  transmitAck (String msg, String ipadress ) throws IOException {
    int no_con_timeout =10000;
    int port = 25901;


    try {
        InetAddress IPAddress =InetAddress.getByName(ipadress);
        byte[] byteBuffer =msg.getBytes();
            Socket client = new Socket();
            client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(IPAddress, port), no_con_timeout);
            client.setSoTimeout(500);
            client.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            out.write(byteBuffer); // Send the encoded string to the server

            // Receive the same string back from the server
            int totalBytesRcvd = 0; // Total bytes received so far
            int bytesRcvd; // Bytes received in last read
            while (totalBytesRcvd < byteBuffer.length) {
                if ((bytesRcvd = in.read(byteBuffer, totalBytesRcvd,byteBuffer.length - totalBytesRcvd)) == -1)
                    throw new SocketException("Connection closed prematurely");

                totalBytesRcvd +=bytesRcvd;}



    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong? Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Can you please post the logcat showing error that you are getting ..

Comment: I am testing it on a device rather than on emmulator

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by preforming the Network operation on Separate thread
using AsyncTask and doInBackground.

Useful links;

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html
[Pass more values in doInBackground AsyncTask Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788161/pass-more-values-in-doinbackground-asynctask-android)